# How do you run a command in iTerm when it launches?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, iterm

I'm working on configuring the iTerm terminal emulator for the Mac to do what I want. Apparently everything is done through what they call "bookmarks." OK, fine. I'm trying to create a bookmark that will open a tab, cd to a certain Rails project, and run the command `script/server`. What's supposed to happen is that this will launch the server daemon ("Mongrel") and I'll see the output scrolling by every time I look at that tab.

In the config dialog, under "command" I put `script/server` and under "working dir" I put the project directory.

What happens is that the tab appears for 1/10th of a second then vanishes.

Recalling a similar problem I had with the Unix screen command, I tried putting a "command" of `bash -c 'script/server'` but the result was identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into that problem because your script runs and then terminates.  All you need to do is put a `read` or something equally sophisticated to say "Press any key to complete script and close window...." at the end of the script.

#### update

I wrote this test script:

```
$ cat echoscript 
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world"
read text
$
```

I created a bookmark so:

```
name: test
command: /Users/chasrmartin/echoscript
Working directory: /Users/chasrmartin
```

When I open the bookmark `test`, I see my "Hello world", and it waits until I type return.  When I type return, it goes away.

Comment: I tried "script/server ; read text ;" and "bash -c 'script/server ; read text ;'" but got the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Tried creating a bash script to launch the Ruby process and putting read text at the end. Got error saying "Rails requires RubyGems" etc. Your solution almost worked, but there's some environment issue I guess.

Comment: Yup, your ruby script is failing; up to now you couldn't tell because the window closed.  I'm guessing you should read this: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/173983